# Set Active Menu Item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do: a regular menu which has the current active page in a different style.

HTML (working properly)

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav">    
        <li>
            <a class="active" href="#">
                <span>one</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>two</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>three</span>
            </a>
       </li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

CSS (working properly)

```
.nav .active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

JS (not working)

```
 $('a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active')
       .siblings()
       .removeClass('active');
 });
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/caveljan/pen/gLyWVY) taken from [Sara Soueidan's Codepen](https://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/bogtz).

Sara Soueidan's version cannot be even replicated in codepen (targetting both the a and the li). Another version that I found was using the following JS:

```
 $('.nav li').click(function() {
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

This version appears to be working, but for some reasons that I don't understand I need to triple click the menu button in order to both use the URL and set the active class.

Can anyone shed some light into this banal matter?

Comment: can you add a demo for the problem where you need to triple click

Answer (score 5):

**Problem:** is with this line `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');`

Actually there are no `siblings` to the `a` within a `li`

**Solution:** You need to first remove the `active` class from `a` tags and then add to `$(this)`

```
$('a.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thank you. I made it work with:  `$('li').click(function() {
  $('li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });` but I still need to triple-click in order to change URL and set active class. I can't replicate this in codepen because I don't have access to URL hierarchy there.

Comment: @JanCavel I dont understand the term `triple check` can you elaborate?

Comment: I am in page `one`. I click the page `two` button, the browser changes URLs, but there is still no active class set for two's `li`, so I have to double-click fast. In total three clicks.

Comment: @JanCavel the browser will reload and all the active classes you set will be removed right..

Answer (score 0):

After more hours than I'd like to admit, I discovered that I didn't even need to set the active class of the 'li' when pushing the menu buttons, but I had to check if the current URL contained that part of the menu.

Therefore, I chained a quick-n-dirty if-elseif in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("one") > -1) {
        $('.nav-container ul li').eq(1).addClass("active");
    } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("two") > -1) {
        $('.nav-container ul li').eq(2).addClass("active");
    } else $('.nav-container ul li').eq(0).addClass("active");
});
```

To test if the URL contained the string "one", I used:

```
window.location.href.indexOf("one") > -1
```

Then I targeted the specific 'li' with eq(i), where i is from 0 to n-1 menu items.

Not the best solution, but it works for a menu with under 5 items, and it also works well if the "one" menu item has some children like "one-one", "one-two" etc.